# Draw a line representing a time period

Tags: php, datetime, draw

There are n channels.  They each have a start time and an end time and they're usually 30-35 days or 90-95 days. However, within those blocks of times there are often 5-20 instances where they weren't doing what they were supposed to be doing for anywhere from 1 second to hours.

I would like to be able to show a chart or draw a line on a page written in php that represents when they were working and when they were not.  I have the start and end date/time for each one and the start and end date/time for each segment where they were not working.

How can I draw a line that represents the entire duration and also shows (in red or whatnot) the periods they were not working?

Comment: You probably need a graphing framework, but this question is too broad to answer as it stands. Break the process down into discreet steps and ask us if you have concrete, focused questions for those steps. And who is 'they'? 'They' sound rather ominous.

Comment: I'm simply asking what the best approach is to periods of time as a line in php as I've never done it and don't know where to start - googling hasn't worked although I'm about to try 'imageline'.  They = channels, as explained in the question. It really doesn't matter what the channels are, it only matters that they represent an entity.  Vote it down is cool, but I don't think this question was unclear or unreasonable.  I've stated I have periods of time and I need to represent them graphically as a line and was asking for advice.

Comment: PHP is normally installed with a 'graphics libray' called 'GD'. use 'phpInfo()' to check if it available. A simple tutorial to draw a line on an image: [php_tutorial/gd-line1](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/gd-line1.php). You can also add text. There are many tutorials available on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the lines could have been alright, but you would still need to break them up into segments represented by color to show the selected time intervals and their "fullness".  Instead using a charting solution was the answer - specifically a heatmap, and it's glorious.  I used Highcharts as seen here: [HighCharts Heatmap](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas)